# Rails: For each 3 records do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently learning rails. I'm trying to figure out the following:

```
<% @obj.{For each 3 records} do |records| %>

<%end %>
```

How would I implement this "for each 3 records"?

What am I trying to do? I would like to display data in 3 columns. Therefore I'm using a table. Each record is a table data (`<td><td>`). After each 3 record I would need to print a `<tr></tr>`.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each_slice` and pass 3 as argument:

```
<% @obj.each_slice(3) do |records| %>
  <%= records %> <!-- your code -->
<% end %>
```

You can add what you need to be printed at the end of each group, something like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each_slice(3) do |element| 
  puts "#{element} group end"
end
# "[1, 2, 3] group end"
# "[4, 5, 6] group end"
# "[7, 8, 9] group end"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to repeat three times? like, maybe:

```
<% 3.times do %>
  ....
  #using @obj.record
  ...
<%end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) for array like:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10].in_groups_of(3, false) do |group| 
  puts group
end

# [1, 2, 3]
# [4, 5, 6]
# [7, 8, 9]
# [10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) or possibly [in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches).

In your controller, you might do something like:

```
@foos = Foo.where(some: :condition)
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @foos.in_batches(of: 3) do |foos_relation| %>
  ... do something with your relation of three foos
<% end %>
```